# Speed up nested for loop with NumPy

Tags: python, image, numpy, loops, nested-loops

I'm trying to write a package about image processing with some numpy operations. I've observe that the operations inside the nested loop are costly and want to speed it up.

Input is an 512 by 1024 image and be preprocessing into a
edge set, which is a list of (Ni,2) ndarrays for each array i.

And next, the nested for loop code will pass edge set and do some math stuffs.

```
###proprocessing: img ===> countour set

img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
high_thresh, _ = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY +             
cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
lowThresh = 0.5*high_thresh
b = cv2.Canny(img, lowThresh, high_thresh)
edgeset, _ = 
cv2.findContours(b,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

imgH = img.shape[0]               ## 512
imgW = img.shape[1]               ## 1024
num_edges = len(edgeset)          ## ~900
min_length_segment_vp = imgH/6    ## ~100



### nested for loop

for i in range(num_edges):
    if(edgeset[i].shape[0] > min_length_segment_vp):

        #points: (N, 1, 2) ==> uv: (N, 2)
        uv = edgeset[i].reshape(edgeset[i].shape[0], 
        edgeset[i].shape[2])
        uv = np.unique(uv, axis=0)

        theta = -(uv[:, 1]-imgH/2)*np.pi/imgH
        phi = (uv[:, 0]-imgW/2)*2*np.pi/imgW
        xyz = np.zeros((uv.shape[0], 3))
        xyz[:, 0] = np.sin(phi) * np.cos(theta)
        xyz[:, 1] = np.cos(theta) * np.cos(phi)
        xyz[:, 2] = np.sin(theta)
    
        ##xyz: (N, 3)
        N=xyz.shape[0]
    
        for _ in range(10):
            if(xyz.shape[0] > N * 0.1):
                bestInliers = np.array([])
                bestOutliers = np.array([])

                #### 
                ####  watch this out!
                ####
                for _ in range(1000):
                    id0 = random.randint(0, xyz.shape[0]-1)
                    id1 = random.randint(0, xyz.shape[0]-1)
                    if(id0 == id1):
                        continue

                    n = np.cross(xyz[id0, :], xyz[id1, :])
                    n = n / np.linalg.norm(n)

                    cosTetha = n @ xyz.T
                    inliers = np.abs(cosTetha) < threshold
                    outliers = np.where(np.invert(inliers))[0]
                    inliers = np.where(inliers)[0]
              
                    if inliers.shape[0] > bestInliers.shape[0]:
                        bestInliers = inliers
                        bestOutliers = outliers
```

What I have tried:

1. I changed np.cross and np.norm into my custom cross and norm
   only work for shape (3,) ndarray. This gives me a from ~0.9s into
   ~0.3s in my i5-4460 cpu.
2. I profile my code and find that now the code inside the most inner loop still cost 2/3 of time.

What I think I can try next:

1. Compile code into cython and add some cdef notation.
2. Translate whole file into C++.
3. Use some faster library for calculation like numexpr.
4. Vectorization of the loop process (but I don't know how).

Can I do more faster? Please give me some suggestions! Thanks!

Comment: 'vectorization' in numpy means  using numpy methods and operators to operate on the whole array.  In effect you replace the python loops with compiled ones.  Notice how `np.cross` works with (n,3) arrays, as opposed to (3,).  That's 'vectorized'

Comment: Your inner loop grows `bestInliers`.  Growing a list is usually faster than creating new larger arrays repeatedly.  I haven't followed the details, but be careful with this.

Comment: I think this is a good case where *Numba* can be used to speed up the computation. Besides this, what is the purpose of doing the same work 10 times? (`for _ in range(10)`)

Comment: hpaulj  Thanks, In fact that I'm going to find the greatest size of Inliers, and I only need the outlier of the bestInlier, which is another ndarray. So that I don't have to create Outlier over and over again. By revising this part, I get a little bit faster.

Comment: Jérôme Richard Thanks, numba do very great in this case! I get almost 5x speed up like ~0.5s --> ~0.1s when the loop size goes larger.  But I can't use numba when I calling another my custom function inside numba function. This is another problem.

Answer (score 1):

The question is quite broad so I'll only give a few non-obvious tips based on my own experience.

- If you use Cython, you might want to change the `for` loops into `while` loops. I've managed to get quite big (x5) speed-ups just from this, although it may not help for all possible cases;
- Sometimes code that would be considered inefficient in regular Python, such as a nested `while` (or `for`) loop to apply a function to an array one element at a time, can be optimized by Cython to be faster than the equivalent vectorized Numpy approach;
- Find out which Numpy functions cost the most time, and write your own in a way that Cython can most easily optimise them (see above point).